# Is it appropriate to remove excessive commenting from code?

Tags: discussion, edits, code

I am referring to this question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17182684/1, where there is a massive amount of commenting within the code (the question has since been edited to correct this).

Is it allowed to remove these for the sake for readability (the comments just specify some lesson details, method comments etc)?

Comment: I was about to make a remark about the sheer lack of comments...then I realized you were talking about their *code*.

Comment: clarified that.

Comment: The current question looks very neat (SO Question)

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

Of course, my OCD trumps my pride and policy of not editing OP's code, so I went ahead and stripped out those comments.  The meat of the question is largely preserved - I'm stunned that the class was so *noisy*.

---

Personally, I'm not a fan of the amount of **code** comments present in the post, but I'm not of the opinion that it should be edited out by *us*.  At least, not yet.

Give the OP a chance to better clarify their question by asking them to remove the redundant noise in the question, and to explicitly state what they're asking.

In retrospect, the comments don't actually *add* much value to the question itself, so asking the OP to clarify better without them should be sufficient.  Removing them might be a bit heavy-handed, but if it improves readability and meaning, then I feel that it'd be a valid edit.

Comment: I didn't notice you'd edited the question, and I was wondering what the OP was talking about. I've edited the question to mention that you've .. uh, edited the question. The other one.

Comment: I think I'll add a link to the original revision, for context.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think an edit was required to make the question readable.

What was most difficult for myself, was the absence of whitespace above comments, making it harder than necessary to scan past them to read just code. I might have first just tried inserting some blank lines to improve the vertical scanning.